# How to search all text files in same folder for a keyword in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, search

How do I search for a keyword in all the text files from a folder? I am using Vista.

Answer (score 4):

> %> findstr 'keyword' *.txt

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/4619/must-have-search-replace-tools-for-text-files),
I can also recommend [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/):

> Agent Ransack is a free tool for
>   finding files and information on your
>   hard drive fast and efficiently. When
>   searching the contents of files Agent
>   Ransack displays the text found so you
>   can quickly browse the results without
>   having to separately open each file!
>
> Agent Ransack provides compelling
>   advantages over similar search tools:
>
> - Regular expressions that allow complex rule based searches.
> - Immediate contents results view.
> - Various wizards to walk the user through the searching process.

Answer (score 1):

Even better: Microsoft or Google Desktop Search (Free Software by M$ and Google).

They are able to index all sort of files (even pdf, doc, xls and that like).

So you can query the index instead of time-wasting searching with the con of having/building a large index and updating it.

Answer (score 0):

To search files by file contents you must first enable it, since by default it's only enabled in indexed locations:

- open any folder
- menu Tools -> Folder Options
- select tab Search, enable Always search file names and contents (might be slow)
- press OK

To search:

- go to the folder where you want to search
- in search box type 'ext:txt keyword' (without quotes)

This will search for word keyword in all file names and contents in txt files. Keyword must be a separate word. To also include cases where keyword is part of a word (either in contents or file name) use wildcards like this

```
ext:c *keyword*
```

Answer (score 0):

The **findstr** may be extremely helpful, but the most powerful tool you're looking for here may be **[grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)**.