# Text file management software

Tags: search, file-management, tags

Is there a software which can tag plain text files, organize and index them like Calibre and provide extensive content searching (I can search the content of the text files)?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/149915/need-text-file-indexing-software http://superuser.com/questions/47796/search-all-text-files-in-same-folder

Comment: I want total text file management software like **calibre**, not just searching or indexing software.

Comment: I know, that's why I haven't closed the question.

Comment: Doesn't Calibre support tagging, organising and indexing of plain text files? The [Calibre FAQ](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/faq.html#what-formats-does-app-support-conversion-to-from) lists TXT as one of the formats it can convert to/from.

Comment: I will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am tempted to say SQLite with the FTS4 full text search extension (standard).

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE text_files USING FTS4(file_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, file_content BLOB);
CREATE TABLE text_information(file_id INTEGER REFERENCES text_files(file_id), file_path TEXT, file_size INTEGER, whatever_you_want…);
```

With some C program it is [easy](http://sqlite.org/quickstart.html) to store a file into your database. Then a simple query performs [full text search (syntax)](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html)

```
SELECT * FROM text_files WHERE file_content MATCH 'hello';
```

Comment: I am looking for more of a software, not building it on my own